# Algorithm for finding chains out of a collection of lines

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Two lines belong to the same chain if they have one endpoint in common. For example 10 lines defined as (0, 0)-(Rnd, Rnd) are one valid chain, because they all have one endpoint in common.

The algorithm I developed is very fast in some lucky cases and very slow in other cases. With 10,000 lines it can take anything between a few seconds and many hours.

I'm looking for advice to speed it up.

The chains are created by a cycle like this:

```
For Each Line in Lines
  If Chain.HasPointInCommonWith(Line) Then
    Chain.Add Line
    Lines.Remove Line
  End If
Next Line
```

To avoid running the test too many times, I sort all the lines about their XMin, and in the loop that looks for curves I added this test:

```
If Line.XMin > Chain.XMax Then Exit For
```

This test works well when the lines represent many rectangles, one on the right of the other, but doesn't help if they are many rectangles one above the other.

Comment: Are you building up many chains?  Are there two loops in the question here?  Or are you trying to build one chain from all these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just putting all of your lines' endpoints in a grid of lists of lines?  Then you simply iterate through your grid and any list with more than two lines in it is a match.

```
    //Build the list
    For Each Line in Lines
      grid[line.ymin][line.xmin].add(line)
      grid[line.ymax][line.xmax].add(line)
    Next Line

    //find the chains
    For current_x and current_y in grid
      if(grid[current_x][current_y].size() != 1)
        continue
      //start a new chain
      line = grid[current_x][current_y][0]
      chain.add(line)
      grid[current_y][current_x][0].remove(line)
      other_endpoint = line.other_endpoint(current_x, current_y)
      grid[other_endpoint.y][other_endpoint.x].remove(line)
      while(grid[other_endpoint.y][other_endpoint.x].size() >= 1)
        line = grid[other_endpoint.y][other_endpoint.x][0]
        chain.add(line)
        grid[other_endpoint.y][other_endpoint.x][0].remove(line)
        other_endpoint = line.other_endpoint(other_endpoint.y,other_endpoint.x)
```

The second loop finds a lone line piece in a grid cell, then checks the grid at the other end of the line (removing itself from the grid in the process).  If there's another line at that position add it to the chain and check that line's other endpoint and so on until there are no other lines to add to that chain.  Then you continue searching for the next chain to start.
This will not catch closed loops (such as A -> B -> C -> A) because of the check `grid[current_x][current_y].size() != 1` will fail for each line here.  If you don't care about preserving these you can simply remove the check completely, otherwise you make a second pass without the check.

Furthermore, if the amount of memory this takes is too high (now the amount memory depends on the extents your lines sit in and not the number of lines anymore) then you can can enlarge the size of each cell to hold a range of positions per cell.  You now have to loop through the lines of each cell to tell if they share endpoints but each cell will ideally have a very small subset of all the lines and so these loops won't be too bad to process.

Comment: The coordinates are floating point, and a NxN grid should help. I will start with something like `N = Sqrt(Lines.Count)`. The points are not randomly distributed, but this system should help a lot.

Comment: This system worked like a charm! I could optimize it by implementing the graph search suggested by mbeckish, using the grid trick to define the set of the adjacent. But the grid without graph search brought the time from 95% of the entire process to less than 0.1%. Now I have other bottlenecks to deal with. (it's an Excel VBA macro that loads the lines from a drawing, searches for features and creates a report)

Comment: Rather than a grid, I'd use a quadtree.

Comment: @DeepYellow (after looking up what a quadtree is) Yes, that would work too, you could control how many levels down the tree splits such that you never have more than N endpoints in any given cell.  Memory usage could be significantly reduced.  Finding an endpoint in a cell would be `O(log N)`, since you have to search for it.

Comment: @GuyGreer You could keep a hash map of endpoints to their cells, making search amortized constant time.

Answer (score 1):

Model your data as a graph, where each endpoint of a line is a vertex, and each line is an edge connecting two vertices.

Then you can use any standard [Graph Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) algorithm to visit all vertices that are connected to a given vertex.

**EDIT**

Once you have defined the graph, pick a vertex and do a DFS to build a tree of connected vertices.

If any vertices are not in this tree, choose one and do another DFS to build another tree.

Repeat until all vertices have been assigned to a tree.

Each tree defines one "chain".

Comment: With 10,000 lines, the starting graph would be 10,000 pairs of vertexes joined by their edge, and all the pairs would be unlinked from each other. The search would need to check each vertex against all the other vertexes (but the ones already checked), and it would be the same as what I am doing now. With the exception that now I have all sorted by XMin, which allows me to get out of the search without going through all the nodes. Wouldn't that be slower than my algorithm? ... or am I missing something?

Comment: Why would they be unlinked?  Aren't you given the edges ("Lines") as input?

Comment: I have 10,000 lines, they are unlinked from each other. If I understand your suggestion I should make a graph with 20,000 nodes (endpoints) and 10,000 edges to form 10,000 pairs. But each of the 20,000 vertexes needs to be compared to all the other vertexes, which will take forever.

Comment: To build the graph, iterate through the list of lines.  For each line, add two vertices (if they don't yet exist) and one edge.  When you are done, you have your vertices and edges, and are ready to start traversing.

Comment: I don't know what point is adjacent to what point. A graph traversal algorithm without the concept of adjacent always requires the exploration of all the nodes, which would be slower than my algorithm with sorted lines, which stops the search when `CurrentChain.Xmax < NextLine.Xmin`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @stenci - Your given set of "Lines" defines which vertices are connected.  Each line is an edge in your graph.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty hash map `M` from `Point` to `List<Line>`
2. For each `Line L`, insert empty lists at `M[L.A]` and `M[L.B]` if they don't yet exist, then do `M[L.A].Add(L)` and `M[L.B].Add(L)`
3. `M` is now a mapping from graph nodes (points) to incident graph edges (lines)
4. Run a depth-first search on this graph using `M` to discover all the chains